# Spring MVC equivalent to ASP.NET RouteData

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm trying to extract a request routing data, similar to RouteData object in ASP.NET, to get the controller and action of the request.
I'm trying to do it inside a filter, but specific Spring implementation will be sufficient.

Is there any way to get that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done from inside a filter. You have to do it with a `HandlerInterceptor` implementation. In the `preHandle` method you can get the PathVariables like this:

```
Map pathVariables = (Map)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Here's a short compiled sample:

Implement the HandlerMapping interface:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Map;

public class ParameterValidationHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Map pathVariables = (Map) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Register the interceptor in the application:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new ParameterValidationHandlerInterceptor());
}
```